# C# Wmi for CPU temperature always returns the same value after first search

Tags: c#, wmi, cpu

I have this code that will return the current temperature reading from the wmi object. The first time it runs I get a good value, however when the code runs again `raw` is always the same number. The only way to get the WMI to actually get a new number is just restart the program. Why is this?

```
public double GetCPUTemperature()
    {
        try
        {
            WMIQueryHelper = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\WMI", "SELECT * FROM MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature");

            foreach (var wmiData in WMIQueryHelper.Get())
            {
                var raw = double.Parse(wmiData["CurrentTemperature"].ToString());

                var fahrenheit = ((raw / 10) - 273.15) * 9 / 5 + 32;
                var celsius = (raw / 10) - 273.15;
                return celsius;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Try googling "wmi MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature not changing" or "wmi MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature not updating" - you will find lots of links - pretty much all saying that using WMI to get the CPU temperature does not work.

Comment: I have already Googled and I know that WMI doesn't get true CPU temperature. I also have Googled and landed on an unanswered Stack Overflow question identical to mine, aside from language. I am asking why doesn't the value update unless I do an application restart.

Comment: This is in one of the pages from the google search _There are some WMI classes that seems to be intended to do such jobs like WMI MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature or Win32_TemperatureProbe classes. But MSDN document clearly states that they are NOT implemented yet. From WMI documentation:
 "Current implementations of WMI do not populate the CurrentReading  property. The CurrentReading property's presence is reserved for future use."  -- i.e. the temperature values are not updated at all._

Comment: So why do they load the first time? My question literally asking, why do they load the first time and then not anymore. Why does restarting my program make the values update?

Comment: If the class is not fully implemented then should there be a reason why you get a value that doesn't change. This same question was asked some time ago [here](https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/wmi-always-returns-the-same-value.3315074/) & an MVP responded : _This class is likely dependent on the hardware vendor. Depending on hardware design and the provider definition, this property may not update the way you think it should._

Answer (score 1):

If you install and start speedfan the temperature is updated to the value speedfan displays.
So there must be a way to trigger the measurement and update the value read from the wmi database within windows.